# Confused about the application of the rule of complements in a specific probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm working on a textbook exercise (see "1" below) and worked through it to arrive at an answer (see "2" below). The textbook provides a solution (see "3" below) in the back of the book, which shows I was wrong. I didn't understand how to arrive at the given answer, so I looked for more explanations online. This is what I found (see "4" below).

**Note: I couldn't figure out how to format my math correctly, sorry. I'm using the nCr notation.*

This explanation makes no sense to me. If 9 out of 18 eggs are spoiled, then 9 out of 18 eggs are also unspoiled. Why does the complement rule apply here? (question is repeated at end of post)

**1) Textbook question:**

15. Odalys sells eggs to restaurants. Before she sends a package of eggs to a customer, she
    selects five of the eggs in the package at random and checks to see if they are spoiled. She
    won’t send the package if any of the eggs she tests are spoiled.
    (a) Suppose the package contains 18 eggs, and half of them are spoiled. How likely is
    it that Odalys detects a spoiled egg?

**2) My answer:**

Sample space = 18 C 5.

Probability = 9 C 5 / 18 C 5 = 0.0147

**3) Textbook answer:**

≈ 0.9853

**4) Explanation I found:**

"Out of 18 eggs, half are spoiled... As the spoiled eggs are 9, she can detect 5 eggs. So it is easer to consider that she can detect an unspoiled egg." Then they perform the same equation I did.
But then, they say "this is the probability of detecting unspoiled eggs, so the required probability is 1 - (9 C 5 / 18 C 5) = 0.9853"

I don't understand this reasoning at all and can't figure out why the complement would even come into play. What is the difference between looking for the probability of 5 spoiled eggs vs 5 unspoiled eggs when 9 eggs are spoiled and 9 eggs are unspoiled?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  You can obtain $\binom{n}{k}$ by typing `$\binom{n}{k}$`.

Comment: Did you calculate the probability that she selected five spoiled eggs or five unspoiled eggs?

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the probability that all of $5$ eggs chosen are spoiled. Required probability is that any of $5$ eggs are spoiled.

Distinguishing all and any is important. Generally, probability of 'all' statement is easier to calculate. The complement of 'any' statement can be described by 'all' statement. Thus, taking complement is effective for this problem.